# Display list by most recent item first

Tags: php, content-management-system

I have an old CMS and i need to edit the code so that it displays the most recent items first as apose to the oldest first. The code below is from the file that i beleive needs editing. Any help most appreciated...

```
<?
require("inc/config.php");

if ($cms->mrow['usrlvl'] < $cms->ulid) {
    header("Location: " . $cms->folder . "/home");
    exit();
}

if (isset($_GET['dm'])) {
    if ($_GET['dm'] == "a") {
        $cms->dmsg = $cms->mrow['singular_title'] . " Added Successfully";
    } else if ($_GET['dm'] == "u") {
        $cms->dmsg = $cms->mrow['singular_title'] . " Updated Successfully";
    } else if ($_GET['dm'] == "d") {
        $cms->dmsg = $cms->mrow['singular_title'] . " Deleted Successfully";
    } else if ($_GET['dm'] == "bd") {
        $cms->dmsg = $_GET['t'] . " "; if ($_GET['t'] > 1) { $cms->dmsg .= $cms->mrow['title']; } else { $cms->dmsg .= $cms->mrow['singular_title']; } $cms->dmsg .= " deleted Successfully";
    }
}

require("inc/header.php");

echo "<h1>" . $cms->mrow['title'] . "</h1>";

// Add button
if ($cms->user['ulid'] <= $cms->mrow['usrlvladd'] && ($cms->mrow['allowadd'] || $cms->user['ulid'] == 1)) echo "<a href=\"" . $cms->folder . "/" . $cms->mrow['tablename'] . "/add\" id=\"add\"><span>Add " . $cms->mrow['singular_title'] . "</span></a>";
// Bulk button
if ($cms->user['ulid'] <= $cms->mrow['usrlvladd'] && $cms->mrow['allowbulkadd']) echo "<a href=\"" . $cms->folder . "/" . $cms->mrow['tablename'] . "/bulkadd\" id=\"add\"><span>Add Multiple " . $cms->mrow['title'] . "</span></a>";

if (!empty($cms->dmsg)) echo "\n<div id=\"dmsg\"><h3><span>" . $cms->dmsg . "</span></h3></div>";

// Set Order BY based on previously saved session or Module Default
if (isset($_SESSION['module' . $cms->mid]['orderby'])) {
    $cms->orderby = $_SESSION['module' . $cms->mid]['orderby'];
} else if ($cms->mrow['orderby'] > 0) { // Get order based on field in module table (default)
    $fres = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM `" . $cms->prefix . "field_" . $cms->tbl . " WHERE fid=" . $cms->mrow['orderby']);
    $cms->orderby = mysql_result($fres,0);
} else if ($cms->mrow['allowposition']) { // Order by ID otherwise
    $cms->orderby = "position";
} else { // Order by ID otherwise
    $cms->orderby = $cms->idname;
}

// Set Order By Direction based on previously saved session or Module Default
if (!empty($_SESSION['module' . $cms->mid]['direction'])) { // Set Order By first based on session if set
    $cms->direction = $_SESSION['module' . $cms->mid]['direction'];
} else { // Order by ID otherwise
    $cms->direction = $cms->mrow['direction'];
}

// List Filter Bar
if ($cms->mrow['allowsearch'] == 1 || $cms->mrow['allownpp'] == 1) $cms->listSearch();

// Set Current page based on previously saved session
if (isset($_SESSION['module' . $cms->mid]['pg']) && is_numeric($_SESSION['module' . $cms->mid]['pg'])) {
    $cms->pg = $_SESSION['module' . $cms->mid]['pg'];
} else {
    $cms->pg = 1;
}



// Generate ajax request to load content into div
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n";
echo "$(document).ready(function(){\n";
if (isset($_GET['upid'])) { $upid = $_GET['upid']; } else { $upid = 0; } // Update Record ID
echo "
document.pg = " . $cms->pg . ";
document.order = '" . $cms->orderby . "';
document.direction = '" . $cms->direction . "';
showModuleList('" . $cms->mrow['tablename'] . "',document.pg,document.order,document.direction,false," . $upid . ");
});
</script>\n";

// Ajax target div
echo "<div id=\"list\"></div>";

require("inc/footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: Its a matter of ordering the database query according the ids or date, or any way you want them to be in order.
Your CMS function orderby seems to be handling the queries, so just use the query you want there...

Comment: to be honest i didn't write this and i wouldn't know where to start to get this to work.